# Display SQLite data to application from Google Drive

Tags: android, sqlite, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I know about Displaying Text or other raw data display, But My Query is about `SQLite` table.

**Query:** Display `SQLite` data to application from `Google Drive`.

I have Uploaded a SQLite Database to `GoogleDrive` which has 5 `tables` including one "`Mobile Number`".

I want to display "`Mobile Number`" to My app **directly** from GoogleDrive. What Options do I have to doing so ?

Comment: SQLite requires direct access to the file. AFAIK, you need to make a copy of the content from Google Drive to a regular file before you can use it with SQLite.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you know how to download a file from Google Drive? Do you know how to open it after you download it?

Comment: @CommonsWare Are you mentioning Drive file while you are saying regular file ?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Looks like you didnt understood my question. Leave it.

Comment: @GameOfThronesSuperFan that is exactly why I ask for classification.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Okay, Yes, I can download and display simple text or other files.

Comment: @GameOfThronesSuperFan how is a database file any different?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Actually, I have a table of "Mobile Number" which I need to display contents users in list view.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I need the data inside table to be displayed. if that is possible that's gonna solve my issue.

Comment: @GameOfThronesSuperFan so what difficult do you have?

Comment: Just download the database file and open it.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thx, I will keep that in mind if I dont get other solution. Looks like your idea is gonna work or else I have to try with JSON.

Comment: you should do what @Code-Apprentic suggested. Because it will be only one time hit to internet otherwise you have to continuously sync up with google drive. other issue will also come on the same page.

Comment: Yes, @jiteshmohite sounds good for me. Thanks for huge response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display "`mobile number`" `table` to your app you have to:

`First>`  download that table using Google Drive Sync or manual Download using Button click.

`Second>` Get table data by accessing the table locally.

`Third>` Display the data to your `View`. Check bellow link for getting example regarding this.

to display data you can check Google Drive Demo examples here "[Click here](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos)"
Hope this will help you.

`JSON` may help but as you mentioned your `database` already growing, you should follow this "`Download and Display`" procedure I mentioned above.

Comment: Thx, this is gonna solve my problem. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0):

instead of uploading sqlite database file on google drive, upload json file with your all data.
and parse json on your app.

Comment: Yes, I can do that. But Already I have a huge database of users in Drive. So, Its going to be tough for me to start JSON. So, Seeking for a solution here. Thx.